# ReactJS: using alert() to take input from user

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I use `alert()` to allow the user to enter their name, and save it to state?

Here is what I have attempted so far:

```
render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={ this.handleChange } />
        <Button>Save</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option would be to use [the `prompt()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt), which displays a modal dialog through which user input can be entered and acquired. The `prompt()` method also allows you to supply a custom greeting, which can be passed as the first argument like so:

```
    const enteredName = prompt('Please enter your name')
```

Integrating this with your existing react component can be done in a number of ways - one approach might be as follows:

```
/* Definition of handleClick in component */
handleClick = (event) => {

    /* call prompt() with custom message to get user input from alert-like dialog */
    const enteredName = prompt('Please enter your name')

    /* update state of this component with data provided by user. store data
       in 'enteredName' state field. calling setState triggers a render of
       this component meaning the enteredName value will be visible via the
       updated render() function below */
    this.setState({ enteredName : enteredName })
}

render: function() {
    return (
      <div>

        {/* For demonstration purposes, this is how you can render data 
            previously entered by the user */ }
        <p>Previously entered user name: { this.state.enteredName }</p>

        <input type="text" onChange={ this.handleChange } />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="Alert the text input"
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean prompt():

```
var userName = prompt('Please Enter your Name')
```

The    userName    variable will contain the user answer.