# How to change state value with prompt in React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I write smth in prompt I want it to change Hayko value... It means, when you open it in browser, it shows cragravorox, after this I I want prompt to change that value of Hayko...

```
const Count = () => {
   const [Hayko, setHayko] = useState('cragoravorox')

   return(
      <>
      <div>{Hayko}</div>
      <button onClick={() => {prompt(('enter my name') )}}> Change me </button>
      </>
   )

}
export default Count
```

Comment: Firstly, you will need to use 'let' instead of 'const'

Comment: then what do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the prompt value to a variable

`const promptValue = prompt(('enter my name')`

and than Use it in the `sethayko(promptValue)` hook onClick like

`<button onClick={() => sethayko(promptValue)}> Change me </button>`

Comment: const Count = () => {
   const [Hayko, setHayko] = useState('cragoravorox')
   const promptValue = prompt('enter my name')


   return(
      <>
      <div>{Hayko}</div>
      <button onClick={() => {setHayko(promptValue)}}> Click me  </button>
      </>
   )

}
export default Count                                                                                                                            I wrote like this, but it doens't work

Answer (score 0):

Found an example of Dacre Denny [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54993218/reactjs-using-alert-to-take-input-from-user)

```html
    const enteredName = prompt('Please enter your name')
//    Integrating this with your existing react component can be done in a number of ways - one approach might be as follows:

/* Definition of handleClick in component */
handleClick = (event) => {

    /* call prompt() with custom message to get user input from alert-like dialog */
    const enteredName = prompt('Please enter your name')

    /* update state of this component with data provided by user. store data
       in 'enteredName' state field. calling setState triggers a render of
       this component meaning the enteredName value will be visible via the
       updated render() function below */
    this.setState({ enteredName : enteredName })
}

render: function() {
    return (
      <div>

        {/* For demonstration purposes, this is how you can render data 
            previously entered by the user */ }
        <p>Previously entered user name: { this.state.enteredName }</p>

        <input type="text" onChange={ this.handleChange } />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="Alert the text input"
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

```
const Count = () => {
  const [Hayko, setHayko] = useState('foo');

  return (
    <>
      <div>{Hayko}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setHayko(prompt('enter my name'))}>Change me</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

No comment on the aesthetics of using prompt :)

Answer (score 0):

You're partway there. You're just missing that you need to use the value returned by the `prompt` call - that will be the value the user enters - and then set the state to that. Here's how to do it with minimal alteration:

```
const Count = () => {
   const [Hayko, setHayko] = useState('cragoravorox')

   return(
      <>
          <div>{Hayko}</div>
          <button onClick={() => setHayko(prompt('enter my name'))}> Change me </button>
      </>
   )

}
export default Count
```

But that's not the easiest to read, so you might want a separate function called something like `handleClick` that makes it clearer what's going on:

```
const Count = () => {
   const [Hayko, setHayko] = useState('cragoravorox')

   const handleClick = () => {
       const newHayko = prompt(('enter my name'))
       setHayko(newHayko)
   }

   return(
      <>
          <div>{Hayko}</div>
          <button onClick={handleClick}}> Change me </button>
      </>
   )

}
export default Count
```

Comment: It worked bro. thanks very much, I will flw you in SO. Thanks very much

Comment: bro it worked but if you can explain me why do we write        setHayko(newHayko)

Comment: because calling `setHayko` sets that state value to the argument you pass it. See for example [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) for explanation.