# ReactJS: How To Get Input Value From The Prompt Box And Update It To Database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, prompt

I'm building a MERN app, I want to let user edit the food name in the prompt box by clicking on the `Edit` **button**.

I was following the instructions in this link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54993218/reactjs-using-alert-to-take-input-from-user]

The issue is when I click on the `Edit` **button** and type in the prompt then click **OK**, it will receive the *null* value for the first time, but it won't update the database.

And then when I click the `Edit` **button** again, without input anything to it then press **OK**, it will receive the value from the first time input and update it to database (like a delay).

What I want is: when click on the `Edit` **button**, it will display the prompt box and take the value from the prompt box and update to the database when the user clicks **OK**.

Is there any way I can fix this? Thank you everyone!

**Here's my demo:** [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qjg2.gif)

**Here's my code:**

```
function FoodListTable(props) {
    /* Definition of handleClick in component */
    const [newFoodName, setNewFoodName] = useState("")

    const handleEdit = () => {
        const enteredFood = prompt('Please enter your new food:')

        setNewFoodName(enteredFood)

        console.log(newFoodName)

        if (newFoodName) {
            Axios.put("https://mern-lefood.herokuapp.com/update", {
                newFoodName: newFoodName,
                id: props.val._id
        })
    }
}

return (
        <button onClick={handleEdit}>Edit</button>
    )
}
```

Comment: Do two things; first log `enteredFood` instead of `newFoodName` state. Second can you move the `console.log(newFoodName)` outside the function and see if the state updates. The reason for this might be that your state is updating but it is not instant since React State Updates are asynchronous (batch update).

Comment: you can use "useEffect", when newFoodName change then call API to update foodName in DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React `this.setState`, and `useState` does not make changes directly to the state object.

React `this.setState`, and `React.useState` create queues for React core to update the state object of a React component.

So the process to update React state is asynchronous for performance reasons. That’s why changes don’t feel immediate.

Try below code that's works !

```
function FoodListTable(props) {
  /* Definition of handleClick in component */
  const [newFoodName, setNewFoodName] = useState("");

  const handleEdit = () => {
    const enteredFood = prompt('Please enter your new food:');
    setNewFoodName(enteredFood);

    if (enteredFood) {
      Axios.put("https://mern-lefood.herokuapp.com/update", {
        newFoodName: enteredFood,
        id: props.val._id
      })
    }
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleEdit}>Edit</button>
  )
}
```

For more detail [Click here](https://linguinecode.com/post/why-react-setstate-usestate-does-not-update-immediately)